# Is spring-data-redis compatible with Spring 3?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redis

I have been looking all over the internet on how to configure Spring MVC 3 with redis but all in vain. I want to connect to redis using *Spring MVC 3*.

I have worked with spring boot and spring-data-redis and everything is working fine. I can connect to redis and store sessions. But the project I am currently working on is legacy based. It uses spring 3 but I believe spring-data-redis is compatible with spring 4 and above. Are there any alternates to make connection between spring 3 and redis. Any tutorial would be helpful.

I expect to store session data like username in the redis using Spring MVC 3

Answer (score 1):

Well, from the documentation of the oldiest available spring-data-redis [release](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.8.23.RELEASE/reference/html/#new-in-1-5-0) 
it looks like the minimal 2.x version is indeed spring 4

However, Spring data redis 1.x should work with spring 3.x:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.4.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#why-spring-redis

Having said that I haven't tried it by myself and if you're only storing sessions in redis, maybe using spring data is an overkill.
After all you can create a Jedis plugin by yourself, expose it as a bean and call the commands directly via the jedis driver. Its also possible to go with reactive client...